# Regex match a word not followed by two other words

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I have some links:

```
utmcsr=rdstation|utmccn=curso-intro-coaching|utmcmd=inbound|utmctr=link3
utmcsr=rdstation|utmccn=agenda-psc|utmcmd=email
utmcsr=rdstation|utmccn=pnl-porto-alegre
```

I want to build a regex expression that matches the **rdstation** not followed by **inbound OR email**.

I've tried `rdstation(?!(email|inbound))` but it doesn't worked.

Comment: This works `^.*?rdstation(?>.*?(?:inbound|email)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your negative lookahead is anchored to the position directly after rdstation.  It would only exclude strings like this:

```
rdstationemail asdf 123 4
```

You need to make sure it can match anywhere after rdstation:

```
rdstation(?!.*(email|inbound))
```

[Working example here](https://regex101.com/r/GKXGuR/1).